# Combining a vlookup with string of text

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone pleaes explain where the syntax is failing for the following formula?

```
Selection.FormulaLocal = "=concatenate(vlookup(" & i & ", _
inputs!A5:B43,2,false), " some words")""
```

The formula works fine if I want to simply use the `vlookup`, but when I try to add text I am coming across syntax errors. Is there a better way to do this without using `FormulaLocal`. Can I combine a vlookup with text any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you do the `concat vlookup` and `text` in another cell and point that cell to `formulalocal`?

Comment: The OP is trying to change `FormulaLocal` in code, not in a spreadsheet cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FormulaLocal property (and the Formula property) expect a string (or string literal) which is the same formula you would type from the Formula bar. You're trying to set an invalid string literal:

```
 "=concatenate(vlookup(" & i & ", inputs!A5:B43,2,false), " some words")""
'<   string literal    >< VBA ><     string literal       ><    VBA  ><string literal>
```

In order to combine two strings, you need to use `&`, otherwise it's invalid VBA code:

```
 "=concatenate(vlookup(" & i & ", inputs!A5:B43,2,false), " & some words & ")""
'<   string literal    >< VBA ><     string literal       ><       VBA     ><string>
```

The string literal is defined with start and end double-quotes. How do you put a double-quote insde a string literal? In VBA you put two double-quotes:

```
 "=concatenate(vlookup(" & i & ", inputs!A5:B43,2,false), ""some words"")"
'<   string literal    >< VBA ><           string literal                >
'Resulting formula (i=5): =concatenate(vlookup(5, inputs!A5:B43,2,false), "some words")
```

Just bear in mind that this is all on the VBA level. The resulting string also has to be a valid formula for Excel. For example, if `i` is not a number but a word, the formula will end up looking like this:

```
=concatenate(vlookup(a word, inputs!A5:B43,2,false), "some words")
```

which is invalid Excel syntax. The solution in this case would be to add double-quotes around `i`:

```
"=concatenate(vlookup(""" & i & """, inputs!A5:B43,2,false), ""some words"")"
```

Comment: Should this work?Dim Text As String
Text = " some words"

Range("A97").Select
Selection.FormulaLocal = "=vlookup(" & i & ",inputs!A5:B43,2,false)" & Text

Comment: As far as VBA syntax it will work, but the resulting forumla will look like this (say `i` is 5): `"=vlookup(5, inputs!A5:B43, 2, false)some words`, which is not a valid Excel formula. I don't know if you'll get a VBA error, or the Excel worksheet will just display an error code.

Comment: Okay. So to add the text I use double quotes within the formula. This way of doing it is called string literal. Using & is simply a string.

Comment: Right. A **`string`** is a [`type`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type), like `Integer`. As a simple example, think about what happens when you add `1` and `2`. If we're talking about strings, you'll end up with `12`. If we're talking about integers (whole numbers), you'll end up with `3`. A **`string literal`** is a an easier way of creating a string than saying `Chr(97) & Chr(98) & Chr(99) & Chr(100)`; instead we can create it in code by writing `"ABCD"`.

Comment: Thanks! One last question. If I want to define say something like this Dim Text1 as String where Text1 = "1" and Dim Text2 where Text2 = "2" I can then combine the two in my code by saying Text1 & Text2 which would give me 12?

Comment: `Dim Is12 As Boolean: Is12 = (Text1 & Text2) = "12"`. `Is12` will be `True`. The parentheses are added for clarity. The second `=` is making the comparison between `Text1 & Text2` and the `"12"` string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `&` insted of `concat`

=`"text" & (vlookupformula)`

so your code will be,

```
Selection.FormulaLocal = "= vlookup(" & i & ", _
inputs!A5:B43,2,false) & " some words"
```

Can you try the following:

```
Dim strWords = "some words"
Selection.formula = "= vlookup(" & i & ", _
    inputs!A5:B43,2,false) "
selection.Formula = .Formula & " & """ & strWords & """"
```

Comment: Selection.FormulaLocal = "=vlookup(" & i & ",inputs!A5:B43,2,false)" & " some words"

Comment: I tried this formula originally, but the compiler won't accept the syntax. I tried adding & " some words" and also & " some words""

Comment: Does `VLookup` itself work with `some words`? If so the issue with the `FormulaLocal` acceptance.

Comment: The FormulaLocal accepts the vlookup. The vlookup itself returns a text value. When I try to add additional text to it- it doesn't work. I think my problem may be with the Formula Local. Can I have the cell recognize a vlookup without a FormulaLocal or a FormulaR1C1?

Comment: Yes you can :) writing it a bit of VBA ;)

Comment: I tried this but it gave me an error.                           Range("A101").Select
Dim strWords As String
strWords = "some words"
Selection.Formula = "= vlookup(" & i & ",inputs!A5:B43,2,false) "
Selection.Formula = .Formula & " & """ & strWords & """"